# Magento URL with get parameters redirects to login

Tags: php, magento, url, parameters

I have a problem in my currently working Magento with the url on a custom extension I am building.

In the `config.xml` I have added a `<routers>` entry wher the `<use>` is using admin and in the `<args>` are the tags `<module>` and `<frontName>`, the url acts well using the Magento `$this->getUrl()` but without adding parameters.

I have a session in admin and if I go to and URL with parameters it will redirect me to login form of admin.

Did someone encoutered this problem, or do you have an ideea from where could it be?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating a admin route theres actually two parts of the config.xml

One is explicit declaration of a route (example):

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <training after="Mage_adminhtml">Training_Animal_Adminhtml</training>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

Take notice that you dont need to specify a `<use>`, this is because the adminhtml tag is declared

The second part of the config is to explicitly declare where will your layout be

```
<adminhtml>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <training_animal>
                <file>training/animal.xml</file>
            </training_animal>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</adminhtml>
```

You probably didn't include the layout file so magento fallback into the login

Comment: Yes, I have the updates on layout but I needed like you have the `/`. Thank you very much